# After wordpress upgrade 4.8, directly accessing wp-admin or while clicking logout - getting bad gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

After wordpress upgrade 4.8.0, directly accessing sitename/wp-admin or while clicking logout - getting bad gateway.

I Tried disable all my plugins and switched to default theme as well. But problem still persist.

i am using nginx and php-fpm

Comment: check the apache error log to find more details. Still, bad gateway is most probably a nginx issue. Test disabling it.

Comment: Did you manually upgrade or automated? My advice is to use wp-cli when upgrading Wordpress (if your hosting provider has no automated way of Wordpress upgrade).

Comment: manually udpated, replaced the core files